# Calculating covariance matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I came across the following covariance matrix calculation:

[image]

How can I calculate the same with `numpy.cov`? I tried following:

```
>>> X=np.array([[1,3,-1],[1,0,-1]])
>>> np.cov(X)
array([[4., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

But this gives different result than the one in the pic.
If `A=[1,3,-1]` and `B=[1,0,-1]`. Then,

```
Mean(A) = 1
Covar(A,A) = Var(A) = ((1-1)^2+(3-1)^2+(-1-1)^2)/3=8/3
```

Then why the `numpy` calculating it as `4`? How the `numpy` is calculating the matrix? And what should I do to get the desired matrix?

Comment: Use `np.cov(X, ddof=0)` -> `array([[2.66666667, 0.66666667], [0.66666667, 0.66666667]])` "ddof=0 will return the simple average" [numpy.cov](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html)

Comment: ohh ... so, **Q1.** you mean its using `n-1=2` instead of `n=3` while finding `Covar(A,A)=((1-1)^2+(3-1)^2+(-1-1)^2)/3=8/3`? **Q2.** Then why it does not use `n-1=2` while calculating `Mean(A)=`(1+3-1)/2=3/2`

Comment: I felt that there wasn't quite enough room in the comments so I've extended out into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way [`cov`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) is called `ddof` will be `1`.

To get the expected results set `ddof=0`:

```
np.cov(X, ddof=0)
```

```
[[2.66666667 0.66666667]
 [0.66666667 0.66666667]]
```

---

There is exactly 1 difference between `np.cov(X)` and `np.cov(X, ddof=0)` which is the *bias* step. With `ddof=1` the `dot` is divided by `2` (`X.shape[1] - 1`), while with `ddof=0` the `dot` is divided by `3` (`X.shape[1] - 0`). See the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2121-L2327) for more information.

---

The general operations performed to calculate `np.cov(X)`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 3, -1], [1, 0, -1]])
X = X.astype('float64')
ddof = 1
avg = np.average(X, axis=1)  # avg [1. 0.]
X -= avg[:, None]
# [[1, 3, -1], [1, 0, -1]] - [[1], [0]]
# array([[ 0,  2, -2],
#        [ 1,  0, -1]])
fact = X.shape[1] - ddof  # 3 - 1 => 2
c = np.dot(X, X.T.conj())
# [[8. 2.]
#  [2. 2.]]
c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)  # divide by 2
```

`c`:

```
[[4. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

---

The general operations performed to calculate `np.cov(X, ddof=0)`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 3, -1], [1, 0, -1]])
X = X.astype('float64')
avg = np.average(X, axis=1)  # avg [1. 0.]
X -= avg[:, None]
# [[1, 3, -1], [1, 0, -1]] - [[1], [0]]
# array([[ 0,  2, -2],
#        [ 1,  0, -1]])
fact = X.shape[1]  # 3 - 0 = 3 <- Same as no Subtraction from shape[1]
c = np.dot(X, X.T.conj())
# [[8. 2.]
#  [2. 2.]]
c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)  # divide by _3_
```

`c`:

```
[[2.66666667 0.66666667]
 [0.66666667 0.66666667]]
```

Comment: (A bit of topic) Default value for `ddof` for `np,cov` is `1` (divide by n-1) and that for [`np.var`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) is `0` (divide by n)? `np.var([1,2,3]) = np.var([1,2,3],ddof=0) = ((1-2)^2+(2-2)^2+(3-2)^2)/3 = 0.6666`. If am correct about differences in default values of `np.cov` and `np.var`, then why is they are kept different?

Comment: That is true `np.cov` with no `ddof` or `bias`  specified means `ddof=1`. While "[b]y default ddof is zero" for `np.var`. That's a design question for which I do not have an answer.

Comment: One more observation: passing single array seem to calculate variance: `np.cov([1,2,6]) # array(7.)`, but passing single array twice seem to return variance in matrix form: `np.cov([[1,2,6],[1,2,6]]) #array([[7., 7.], [7., 7.]])` A bit weird but just guessing what might be the reason...