# reconstruct Covariance matrix from dataset generated given that Covariance matrix (using Cholesky factorization)

Tags: python, matrix-factorization, covariance-matrix

Recalling that `C = L@L.T` using [Cholesky](https://scicoding.com/how-to-calculate-cholesky-decomposition-in-python/) factorization,
I'm trying to repeat transformations described in [this article](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/08/use-the-cholesky-transformation-to-correlate-and-uncorrelate-variables.html) with `Python`, but am having some misunderstanding & inability to return initially given *Covariance matrix* from generated dataset given that covariance matrix. The question is how to get covariance matrix back?

```
# Importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = [[9,1], [1,1]]   # given Sigma (or covariance matrix)

U= la.cholesky(sigma, lower=False)
rec= U.T@U

print(pd.DataFrame({'U': U[:,1], 'rec1':rec[0],  'rec2':rec[1]} ))

# generate x,y ~ N(0,1), corr(x,y)=0
xy = U.dot(np.random.normal(0,1,(2,1000)))
##print(xy)
L= U.T
zw = L @ xy     # Z and W variables - correlated
cov = np.cov(zw, ddof=0)    # ?????????? /* did we succeed? Compute covariance of transformed data */
print(cov)
# [[86.66333557 10.85423541]
# [10.85423541  2.1026003 ]]

plt.scatter(zw[0], zw[1])
plt.show()
```

P.S. used `ddof=0` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432422/calculating-covariance-matrix-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem in the article still seems to be in `U= la.cholesky(sigma, lower=False)`. When we take `L` as *Lower Triangular matrix* instead, then example becomes OK

```
# Importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = np.array([[9,1], [1,1]])

L= la.cholesky(sigma, lower=True)
print(L)
rec= np.dot(L, L.T.conj())           # L.T@L
print(rec)
print(pd.DataFrame({'L': L[1, :], 'rec1':rec[0],  'rec2':rec[1]} ))    
##  0.333333   9.0   1.0
##  0.942809   1.0   1.0
print(np.allclose( rec, sigma, rtol= 1.4e-01, atol= 1.4e-01))

# generate x,y ~ N(0,1), corr(x,y)=0
xy = np.random.normal(0,1,(2,10000))
zw = L @ xy     # Z and W variables - correlated
cov = np.cov(zw, ddof=0)    #  /* did we succeed? Compute covariance of transformed data */
print(cov)
##[[9.22566851 1.02844567]
## [1.02844567 0.97824299]]

plt.scatter(zw[0], zw[1])
plt.show()
```